# How to create a print function in python

Tags: python, function, class, methods, printing

I tried to program a new type of print function, I wanted that the text was printed out in procedural way, so I wrote this:

```
def print(text):
    for t in text:
        sys.stdout.write(t)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1) 
print('Monkey')
#program stamp  Monkey  letter by letter with delay of 0.1 sec
```

But, if instead of 'Monkey', I  put inside ('text', object.param, 'text') it doesn't work;

An example is:

```
class Monkey:
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=str

Monkey.name = 'George'

def print(text):
    for t in text:
        sys.stdout.write(t)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
print('Monkey', Monkey.name, 'is funny')

#TypeError: print() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

How I can program this new print for get the same functionality of the normal print but with the additional of possibility of delay?

Comment: the simplest thing to do is change `def print(text)` to `def print(*text)`

Comment: perfect!! 
But now i would like that the delay could be letter by letter, how i can do?

Comment: If you want to delay letter by letter, see @bichanna's answer since his/her answer does what you want.

Comment: Perfect!! TX! another thing: if i would like that it print other int and more variables than only string how i could do?  (cause actually it give me error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
def print(text)
```

to this:

```
def print(*texts)
```

It accepts many args more than one.

And do this:

```
def print(*texts):
    for text in texts:
        for t in text:
           sys.stdout.write(t)
           sys.stdout.flush()
           time.sleep(0.1)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to print out int as well, you can convert int to str:

```
def print(*texts):
    for text in texts:
        text = str(text) # Notice!! I added this line
        for t in text:
           sys.stdout.write(t)
           sys.stdout.flush()
           time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Perfect!! TX!
another thing: if i would like that it print other int and more variables than only string how i could do?

Comment: You can just convert int to str like this: `str(38)`, and then you can pass it to the function.

Comment: but how i can integrate in the code? i mean, there is a way for what he automatically convert all the text that process in string?

Comment: What do you mean? The updated code convert everything from boolean to double to int into string inside the function. So, I think you can just copy my answer, paste it to your text editor, and run it.

Comment: Oh, sorry ahahah, i didn't see, sorry so much ahahah

Answer (score 0):

You can add a star sign before the argument text.

```py
class Monkey:
     def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=str

Monkey.name = 'George'

def print(*text):
    for t in text:
        sys.stdout.write(t)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
print('Monkey', Monkey.name, 'is funny')
```